# Why doesn't "xargs sudo perf top" work as expected?

Tags: linux, pipe, sudo, xargs, perf

I want to profile a process, so first get its pid, then use "`perf top`" to check it:

```
$ pgrep program
14472
$ sudo perf top -p 14472
```

It works as expected:

[image]

Then I want to use pipe to connect these two commands, so I use `xargs`:

```
$ pgrep program | sudo xargs perf top -p
```

But this time "`perf top`" seems not work normally:
[image]
I compared processes of these two operations:
(1) Run `pgrep` and `perf` separately:

```
$ ps -ef | grep perf
root      18468  16827  0 09:34 pts/3    00:00:00 sudo perf top -p 14472
root      18469  18468 91 09:34 pts/3    00:00:06 perf top -p 14472
nanxiao   18477  18295  0 09:34 pts/4    00:00:00 grep --color=auto perf
```

(2) Use `xargs` to connect `pgrep` and `perf`:

```
$ ps -ef | grep perf
nanxiao   18250  16827  0 09:32 pts/3    00:00:00 xargs sudo perf top -p
root      18251  18250  0 09:32 pts/3    00:00:00 sudo perf top -p 14472
root      18252  18251 87 09:32 pts/3    00:01:47 perf top -p 14472
nanxiao   18442  18295  0 09:34 pts/4    00:00:00 grep --color=auto perf
```

IMHO, it seems same. Anyone can give some clues? Thanks in advance!

P.S., my OS is `CentOS 7`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After checking [manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html) again, I find `-o` option can fix this issue:

> -o, --open-tty
> Reopen stdin as /dev/tty in the child process before executing
> the command.  This is useful if you want xargs to run an
> interactive application.

The command is like this:

```
$ pgrep program | sudo xargs -o perf top -p
```

But unfortunately, `CentOS 7`'s `xargs` is a little old, and doesn't provide this option.

The root cause is: without `-o` option, the `stdin` of `perf` program is `/dev/null`:

```
$ sudo lsof -p 1495
......
perf    1495 root    0r      CHR    1,3       0t0     2052 /dev/null
......
```

And the `perf` is blocked in  [SLang_getkey()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/tools/perf/ui/tui/setup.c#L83):

```
    ......
    FD_ZERO(&read_set);
    FD_SET(0, &read_set);

    if (delay_secs) {
        timeout.tv_sec = delay_secs;
        timeout.tv_usec = 0;
    }

    err = select(1, &read_set, NULL, NULL, ptimeout);

    if (err == 0)
        return K_TIMER;

    if (err == -1) {
        if (errno == EINTR)
            return K_RESIZE;
        return K_ERROR;
    }

    key = SLang_getkey();
    if (key != K_ESC)
        return key;
    ......
```

Read of `/dev/null` will return `EOF`, then `select()` will return `1`.

With `-o` option the `stdin` of `perf` program is `/dev/tty`:

```
$ sudo lsof -p 1394
......
perf    1394 root    0u      CHR 136,25       0t0       28 /dev/pts/25
......
```

In above code, the `select()` will return `0`, and the whole function will return accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

A better approach would be to directly run the `top` on the output of `pgrep` instead of piping over `xargs`. I believe `top` command by default does not read information over standard input

```sh
sudo perf top -p "$(pgrep program)"
```

This way the `$(..)` returns the output of the `pgrep` command and the returned value is passed as a positional argument value to the `-p` flag.

Comment: Indeed, perf top does seem to be broken by taking input from a closed pipe.  `cat /dev/null | sudo perf top` never gets past "Collecting samples...", but `sudo perf top` on a terminal works normally for me.